# virtualenv, python and subversion

Tags: python, svn, virtualenv, pip

I'm trying to use the python subversion SWIG libraries in a `virtualenv --no-site-packages` environment. How can I make this work?

Comment: Why do you say it's impossible? Do you see an error when you try? What did you try? If you see the error, what is it?

Comment: Problem is that official installation way is using apt-get and there is no package at pypi repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog post answers my question nicely. http://codersbuffet.blogspot.com/2009/09/mercurial-subversion-and-virtualenv.html

Comment: That doesn't seem very "deployable".  That solution will work for a machine at a time.  I wonder if there is a way to do this in a generic way using requirements.txt or setuptools.

Answer (score 5):

You can install it inside virtualenv from svn:

```
source /home/you/venv/python/bin/activate
pip install -e svn+http://pysvn.tigris.org/svn/pysvn/tags/pysvn/Extension/1.7.6/#egg=pysvn
```

Comment: That source is (currently) password protected.

Answer (score 1):

According to Maciek Sawicki answer:

```
. ap/bin/activate
(ap) $ pip install http://pysvn.barrys-emacs.org/source_kits/pysvn-1.7.6.tar.gz
```